# nasm dos interrupt (output string)

Tags: windows, assembly, int, nasm

I have the following code:

```
    %include "io.inc"

section .data
msg db 'Hello World...$'

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    ;write your code here

     mov ah,09
     mov dx,OFFSET msg
     int 21h
     xor eax, eax
     xor dx,dx
     ret
```

and it gets the next error:

> [19:28:32] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
>   C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/SASM/program.asm:12: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
>   gcc.exe: error: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/SASM/program.o: No such file or directory

What is the problem? i'm using sasm ide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is TASM/MASM syntax:

```
mov dx,OFFSET msg
```

When using NASM you'd simply write:

```
mov dx,msg
```

Comment: now there's another error for the same line:  COFF format does not support non-32-bit relocations

Comment: You're writing real-mode DOS code. Such code would have to be compiled into a DOS EXE or COM file, and be executed in DOS (or something that can run DOS executables, like Windows 9x or DOSBox). I don't know what commands the SASM IDE uses to build.